# Hangman game problems in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my complete code:

```
import random
guessesMade = 0
lives_remaining = 8
roundsPlayed = 0
roundsWon = 0
guessed_letters = ''
words = ['chicken', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'frog']

def pick_a_word():
    word_position = random.randint(0, len(words) - 1)
    return words[word_position]
    print(pick_a_word())

def play():
    print('Welcome to hangman! The rules are simple: A word will be chosen at random and will be represented by a sequence of blanks. Each blank constitutes a letter in the word. You will be asked to enter a letter and if the letter is contained in the word you will be notified. You can only make an incorrect guess 8 times before you lose the round. To win the round you must guess all the letters and reveal the word. Good luck!\n\n')
    word = pick_a_word()
    while True:
        guess = get_guess(word)
        if process_guess(guess,word):
            print('You won.')
            break
        elif lives_remaining == 0:
            print("\nI'm sorry, but you have run out of guesses. The word was {}.".format(randWord))
            break

def get_guess(word):
    print_word_with_blanks(word)
    print('Lives Remaining: ' + str(lives_remaining))
    guess = input('Guess a letter or the word if you know it.')
    return guess

def print_word_with_blanks(word):
    display_word=''
    for letter in display_word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter) > -1:
            display_word = display_word + letter
        else:
            display_word = display_word + '-'
    print(display_word)

def process_guess(guess,word):
    if len(guess) > 1 and len(guess == len(word)):
        return whole_word_guess(guess,word)
    else:
        return single_letter_guess(guess, word)

def whole_word_guess(guess,word):
    global guessesLeft
    if guess.lower() == word.lower():
        return True
    else:
        guessesLeft -=1
        return False

def single_letter_guess(guess,word):
    global guessed_letters
    global lives_remaining
    if word.find(guess) == -1:
        lives_remaining -= 0
    guessed_letters = guessed_letters + guess.lower()
    if all_letters_guessed(word):
        return True
    return False

def all_letters_guessed(word):
    for letter in word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter.lower()) == -1:
            return False
        return True
play()
```

Sorry for the big code block, but I wanted to provide a look at the full program to help with fixing my mistakes. As of now once play is called it just keeps printing out 'Lives remaining 8:' when I enter a single letter in. After a few letters it just prints out 'You won.' I am having trouble finding my mistakes and any help from python experts would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it should be in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nah this is not for codereview - the program doesn't work

Comment: Here's a hint about the lives remaining not decrementing. What does this line do?
`lives_remaining -= 0`

Comment: Of course! Stupid mistake but totally get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
def print_word_with_blanks(word):
    display_word=''
    for letter in display_word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter) > -1:
            display_word = display_word + letter
        else:
            display_word = display_word + '-'
    print(display_word)
```

You are ignoring the `word` passed in as a parameter, and looping through `display_word`, which is empty. So the actual word (with spaces) is never printed at all.

Presumably you mean to say:

```
    for letter in word:
        ...
```

Or you can write it a little more concisely:

```
def print_word_with_blanks(word):
    print(''.join(c if c in guessed_letters else '-' for c in word))
```

Another problem you are having is here:

```
def all_letters_guessed(word):
    for letter in word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter.lower()) == -1:
            return False
        return True
```

The way this is indented, it always returns true or false on the first iteration of the loop. It should be like this:

```
def all_letters_guessed(word):
    for letter in word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter.lower()) == -1:
            return False
    return True
```

so the `return True` only fires after the whole loop has finished.

Or better still:

```
def all_letters_guessed(word):
    return all(c.lower() in guessed_letters for c in word)
```

Comment: Yes I see that mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. Works very well now.

Comment: Everything is working great, but I am running into one problem...if the user guesses the first letter in the word the program immediately registers it as a win. I'm trying to find the mistake, but do not see it. Maybe a wiser pair of eyes can spot it. So if the the word was 'rhino' I would start with - - - - -. If my first guess was an r, it is an automatic win. Strange

Comment: @Droxbot The problem is in `all_letters_guessed`. See the new stuff in my answer.